# How to enforce Resource Limits/Requests on all resources in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I know that I can [create a LimitRange](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/memory-default-namespace/#create-a-limitrange-and-a-pod) in a namespace. Then all pods created in *that* namespace will have Resource (CPU/Memory) Limits/Requests set.

So my initial question of how to enforce Resource Limits/Requests on all resources in a kubernetes cluster seems to be equivalent to: How do I enforce a LimitRange exists in every namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible to enforce `LimitRange` and `ResourceQuota` cluster-wide, that is, providing defaults for every namespace. I'm aware of at least [one discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17097) to potentially change this.